# How WebDriver Actions works

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am interested in mechanism of WebDriver actions.
For example

```
 var actions = new Actions(driver);
 var action = actions.MoveToElement(element).Build();
 action.Perform();
```

How method MoveToElement() works? Is it a wrapper on javascript?
If yes, is it possible to get this javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - I was actually curious about the mechanics myself, so I took a look through the selenium source, and my determination is that - no. It does not use javascript.  It uses Java's ability to read / move the mouse positions / keyboard drivers / etc, and then when you call `perform()`, it has a queue of `Actions` that it will then perform.

Answer (score 1):

moveToElement is implemented based on coordinates.
following is the code for moveToElement is the following

```
public Actions moveToElement(WebElement toElement) {
    this.action.addAction(new MoveMouseAction(this.mouse,
            (Locatable) toElement));
    return this;
}


public abstract interface Locatable {
public abstract Coordinates getCoordinates();
}

public class MoveMouseAction extends MouseAction implements Action {
public MoveMouseAction(Mouse mouse, Locatable locationProvider) {
    super(mouse, locationProvider);
    if (locationProvider == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Must provide a location for a move action.");
}

public void perform() {
    this.mouse.mouseMove(getActionLocation());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No javascript. It uses coordinates to move mouse there. Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#git/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions%253Fstate%253Dclosed) link.